# Add and remove objects from list with Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to get a grip around *Linq* and have the following problem:

I have a list of a custom object, with a few properties for each object. I then have another list of the same type, where the property values will be different except for an ID property. Now, I want to add the objects that is found in my second list (`tempList`) that is not found in my first list (`OrderList`). After that I try to remove objects in `OrderList` that is not found in `tempList`.

This might seem a bit unnecessary, but the reason is that I need to keep the values of properties in `OrderList` if the ID of these are found in the `tempList`, hence not replace the object in `OrderList` with "*empty*" properties from `tempList`.

The code snippet looks like this (`OrderList` and `tempList` has already been filled with objects, and it's the property *ID* I use as identifier):

```
// Add new orders from account to current object
OrderList.AddRange(tempList.Where(p => !OrderList.Any(p2 => p2.ID == p.ID)));

// Remove missing orders from our OrderList
OrderList.RemoveAll(p => !tempList.Any(p2 => p2.ID == p.ID));
```

There is something I'm doing wrong since the properties of an object in OrderList gets reset after each of the two lines...

Maybe a fresh set of eyes can see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Your code looks fine, and when I try it it runs as you'd expect. What exactly do you end up with in `OrderList` - the original contents, the contents of `tempList`, some mixture but not the one you want? Where does `OrderList` come from?

Comment: What do you mean by _properties of an object in OrderList gets reset_? One object in particular? Are property values reset to default values?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
void Main()
{
    var orList = new List<A> {new A {Id = 0, S = "a"}, new A {Id = 1, S = "b"}, new A {Id = 2, S = "c"}, new A {Id = 4, S = "e"}};
    var tmList = new List<A> {new A {Id = 2, S = "cc"}, new A {Id = 3, S = "dd"}};

    var result = orList.Union(tmList, new AComparer()).ToList();
    result.RemoveAll(a => tmList.All(at => at.Id != a.Id));
}

public class A {
    public int Id;
    public string S;
}

class AComparer : IEqualityComparer<A> {
    public bool Equals(A x, A y) { return x.Id == y.Id; }
    public int GetHashCode(A a) { return a.Id; }
}
```